# M2 Paypal configure buttons greyed out

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-express, paypal-standard

The Configure buttons for all the paypal options are disabled in my admin panel.  I have checked all website / store scopes and they are grayed out for all.

I have verified my version of php 7.0.12 has all required items (iconv, mhash, etc - I went though the list on the magento sys reqs page).

The site is running on ssl.

Does anyone have any ideas?